# How do I perform PUT operation via Gitlab's API?

Tags: api, curl, gitlab, crud, readme

I want to construct a curl command using Gitlab's API so that I can edit a README.md file. I know it is possible according to docs:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html

I am able to find my project with `curl 'https://private.private.io/api/v4/56/projects?private_token=private-token'`but I can't seem to go any deeper in order to read or edit a file in repo.

*UPDATE*

The solution is

```
curl --request PUT --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: private-token' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"branch": "master", "author_email": "email", "author_name": "name",
"content": "status, building", "commit_message": "update file"}' 'https://private.private.io/api/v4/projects/56/repository/files/README.md'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using this solution mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository).THis allows you to update a single file

```
curl --request PUT --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>' --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"branch": "master", "author_email": "author@example.com", "author_name": "Firstname Lastname", \
    "content": "some content", "commit_message": "update file"}' \
  'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fproject%2Erb'
```